# Send raw file data using FileReader

Tags: javascript, axios, redmine

I am facing some issues trying to send raw file data using a FileReader.
I'm trying to create an attachment in Redmine and the body of the request here, has to be the raw file data. The problem is that the data sent are a bit different from the original file, which make it corrupted in the end.

Code used:

```
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.onload = async () => {
   const fileContent = reader.result
   await this.$api.post(`${this.url}?filename=${file.name}`, fileContent,
   {
      headers: {
         'X-Redmine-API-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
         'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      },
   })
}
reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
```

Original file opened in notepad:
[image]

Resulting file opened in notepad:
[image]

As you can see, the content differs a bit from original. Why ? What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you should use `reader.readAsDataURL(file)` then `const fileContent = reader.result.split(',').pop()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this piece of code and sadly, the result is even worse... I just get a file with one line full of text.